# Regular expression, filtering expected data from an array like ":key{value}"

Tags: php, regex

Example:

```
$match_check = "(?'txt'(?<=:txt{)([^}]+)(?=}))|(?'reg'(?<=:reg{)([^}]+)(?=}))";

$route_from_value = ':txt{resultxt}:txt{test}:reg{/^[a-zA-Z]*$/}:reg{regexresult}';

preg_match_all('/'.$match_check.'/', $route_from_value, $get_matchers_check);

var_dump($get_matchers_check);
```

And result for given question are:

```
array(7) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "test"
    [2] =>
    string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "regexresult"
  }
  'txt' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "test"
    [2] =>
    string(0) ""
    [3] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "test"
    [2] =>
    string(0) ""
    [3] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "test"
    [2] =>
    string(0) ""
    [3] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  'reg' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
    [1] =>
    string(0) ""
    [2] =>
    string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "regexresult"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
    [1] =>
    string(0) ""
    [2] =>
    string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "regexresult"
  }
  [4] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
    [1] =>
    string(0) ""
    [2] =>
    string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "regexresult"
  }
}
```

But, expected result should be (how make it only with regexp?) or something simply:

```
 'txt' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
  },
 'txt' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "resultxt"
  }
 'reg' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
  }
 'reg' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "regexresult"
  }
```

Comment: It is not possible to produce the output you want. It is simply because the `preg_match_all` doesn't output in such format: note how the outer array indices correspond to capturing group and the inner array indices correspond to the matches.

Comment: You're using regex to parse a string which contains a regex?  Sounds way complicated.  To approach this I would not use regex, a split on `:` and then simple string operations for `{` and `}` might be a much easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm working something complicated scripts that can be used for another  simple getting data on another PHP class for a reason. I've already splitted but, can be like `:txt`, `:reg`, `:num` etc... for a reason.

Comment: Actually, if a string contains a regex, it is very hard to parse the string correctly. How do you know `}` is part of the regex, or part of the delimiter outside?

Comment: I'm using already script that really working using closure tag `<?=` and separate brackets `{}`, this isn't problem... but this isn't my question. This part has been already fixed what you need.

Comment: I think it's solution in a `preg_split()`

Comment: The _expected_ output you're after is simply wrong... You **cannot** have multiple `key` values which are the same in one array.

Comment: If I have multiple key what it can't go inside arrays like `regex` with arrays `0,1,2,3....`. I know that one array can overwritten if repeats.

Comment: In your expected output you show an array which features both `txt` and `reg` as keys twice. I.e. you're trying to say that `$array['reg'] = XXX` **and** `$array['reg'] = YYY` which, obviously, cannot be true.

Comment: It's already discussed this, and know of it. But it can be as arrays result as nested child, look at simple answer on nhahtdh. I'm trying to find a simpler answer but there isn't, because it's searching all of arrays and you must check all keys of arrays and getting a value.

Comment: I've looked at the answer and it doesn't seem to output anything like what you suggest you want it to? My understanding was that you wanted to have output like `$array = array('txt' => array('resulttxt','test'), 'reg' => array(...));` which you could have achieved with just using `array_filter`?

Comment: Look under `reg` key. There are 2 results. Inside that on key `0` and key `1` is empty but it can be check using `isset` or `array_filter()`. There are on key `2` and `3` for the result of `reg` key so there is answer inside arrays. (2 results inside one array for `reg`). I think without using key pairs and checking like `isset` and checking value inside array only solved this problem.

Comment: Yes, `0` and `1` are empty for `reg` because the first two matches were for `txt`. But if you use `array_filter($matches['reg')` then it will remove `0` and `1`; Is that not what you're after?

Comment: If I know that main `reg` key is reg, a only checks in a loop and checks a data inside arrays. I don't want to know and do with empty arrays because it isn't important, and isn't important on which arrays is such as on `0` or on `2` and similar..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37405/discussion-between-steven-and-marin-sagovac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `preg_match_all` and `preg_split` function follows a format that doesn't match what you want.

What you can do is just do some post-processing on the output of `preg_match_all` to obtain the result (something like an array of `['key', 'value']` pair). Note that you should set the flag [`PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to obtain the index of the match for comparison. A capturing group that **matches nothing** will give index `-1` or will **not** return an array that contains 2 elements.

By the way, you can remove some unnecessary capturing group from your regex.

```
"(?'txt'(?<=:txt{)[^}]+(?=}))|(?'reg'(?<=:reg{)[^}]+(?=}))"
```

Sample run:

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/(?\'txt\'(?<=:txt{)[^}]+(?=}))|(?\'reg\'(?<=:reg{)[^}]+(?=}))/', ':txt{resultxt}:txt{test}:reg{/^[a-zA-Z]*$/}:reg{regexresult}', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'resultxt',
      1 => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'test',
      1 => 19,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
      1 => 29,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'regexresult',
      1 => 48,
    ),
  ),
  'txt' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'resultxt',
      1 => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'test',
      1 => 19,
    ),
    2 => // No match found, index -1
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => -1,
    ),
    3 => // No match found, index -1
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => -1,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'resultxt',
      1 => 5,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'test',
      1 => 19,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => -1,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => -1,
    ),
  ),
  'reg' => 
  array (
    0 => '', // No match found, not array of 2 elements [<matched text>, <index>]
    1 => '', // No match found, not array of 2 elements [<matched text>, <index>]
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
      1 => 29,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'regexresult',
      1 => 48,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => '',
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
      1 => 29,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'regexresult',
      1 => 48,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: True, I can grab using `key` and get a data but, I need using `array_filter()` to remove empty arrays from the result. But on `regex101` a same script that I'm using, and `regex101` is page written in PHP is filtered correctly and empty values. That's weird, and I think that is bad solution when you using `regex101` pages that filters all empty array but you don't expected.

Comment: I think there aren't another solution or I complicated my life already :(

Comment: @MarinSagovac: Empty element are correct, since nothing is captured in those capturing groups. In this case, since you know that the matches are mutual exclusive (one branch matches, meaning other branches will not match), for each inner index, just filter out the one with > 0 index.

Comment: Okay filtering a result solved this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, pointing to a key values and checking `isset()` is also good idea. Thank you!